# Why does my Cordova app crash on iOS 15 but not iOS 14?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, web-applications

I've got two sets of iPad apps for a client that perform fine on iOS 14.4. When loaded onto an iPad running iOS 15 or higher, the apps reset every 6 seconds or so and do not register any input.

Looking at the profiler in Xcode, the memory and CPU spike before crashing. I am also loading a bunch of local iframes in the app that take up a considerable amount of space.

The following cordova plugins are being used and allow the app to run on iOS 14 or below:

- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
- cordova-plugin-printer
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
- cordova-plugin-wkwebviewfix (allowed the iframes to be loaded locally)

The issue is the app is useless right now when run on iOS 15 and I am lost (little to no iOS experience, this is a web app that a client requested be put on an ipad for local use off of wifi).

Does anyone have any leads as to why a cordova app that works on ios 14 wouldn't on ios 15?